# Структура бд продукции mysql

Tags: php, mysql, form

Есть каталог продукции, т.е. категория -> продукт. Проблема в том что в разных категориях, кол-во полей в продукте может отличаться. К примеру если продукт в категории1, у него два поля(название, описание), если категория2 то у товара уже 3 поля(название, краткое описание, полное описание). При этом таблица под продукты одна, назовем ее items к примеру. Так вот как лучше организовать структуру бд ? Я вижу два варианта, хранить все возможные поля в таблице items или создать таблицу под поля продуктов, т.е. как-то так

> items_fields
>
> id item_id field_name

Но тогда нужна еще одна таблица под содержимое полей,

> fields
>
> id items_fields_id content

в итоге получается слишком сложно.

Может кто посоветует еще варианты ?

Всем спасибо, решил все таки остановиться на варианте с несколькими таблицами.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать 4 таблицы
1 таблица, это category с колонками id, name.
2 таблица, это products, с колонками id, name, category_id.
3 таблица, это property, с колонками id, name, product_id.
4 таблица, это property_values, с колонками, id, description, property_id(желательно на эту колонку повесить UNIQUE INDEX, чтобы id был уникальных, только 1 значение для одного свойства - ну это если надо)

В итоге имеем, в одной категории может быть много продуктов, в 1 продукте может быть много свойств, тобишь "Краткое описание" или "Полное описание" или как хочешь назови другие свойства, и соответственно значение для этих свойств "Это хороший товар". и можно будет добавлять, в 1 товаре хоть 10 разных свойств, а в другом только 2

Comment: Спасибо, с этим разобрался. Теперь вопрос в том как выводить это дело, т.е. к примеру поле html формы, может быть textarea, а может быть просто text к примеру. Пока что думаю сделать колонку type в БД типа text, и в нем задавать тип(textarea, text и т.д.).

Comment: а причем тут html? при передаче в переменную например GET или POST, там же не пишется что данные пришли из textarea или инпута text ))) в бд если знаете сколько кол-во слов то ставьте VARCHAR(огранич кол-во) если заведома не знаете сколько будет символов то ставьте тип TEXT и всё, на данном этапе этого хватит.
Выводить это всё дело можете через JOIN-ы. одним запросом получите все данные.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, пошел творить :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант хранить максимально возможное количество полей в продуктовой таблице. У вас же наверняка есть шаблоны - пусть они выводят только те поля, которые нужны в рамках этого шаблона. Если вы хотите все же отфильтровать вывод на уровне модели или контроллера, можно с таблицей категорий свяжите таблицу, которая будет хранить список свойств, которые должны отображаться с данной категории.